# C++ what is the difference of type * and type *& in function

Tags: c++, pointers

I have two function signatures in C++

```
void printArray(int* arrayPtr);
void printArray(int*& arrayPtr);
```

I understand the 1st function. It says the function takes in a arrayPtr argument which is of type that's a pointer pointing to an integer.

Both function signature works, but I have a hard time understanding the 2nd signature(`*&`) and what benefits it offers?

Comment: Ask yourself, " What if I want the function to change the address the pointer's pointing at?"

Comment: Read it from right to left. It's a reference to a pointer.

Comment: Thinking on this a bit more, we may have to back up a bit. Are you familiar with references in C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's exactly the same as `type` versus `type&`; the first is a value and the second is a reference. The fact that `type` is a pointer doesn't change that.

Comment: I can't imagine there's no existing answer to what a reference to a pointer is

Comment: This is a pretty clear answer.  Putting `&` at the end of any type has a very consistent effect.